# GROUP BY range of timestamp values

Tags: sqlite, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I spent a lot of time reading and still can't find the best solution. I am designing an Android Calorie Counter Application and I'm using SQLite.
I have a table `food_logs` in which I have 2 fields: `log_date(NUMBER) , food_id(NUMBER)`. I save the dates as unix timestamp. I want to retrieve all the foods a person has eaten by days.

For example all foods eaten today or 2012-05-20( yesterday). I was searching GROPBY timestamp but I got nowhere.

Or I just need to save date as a string ( which I think is not the best practice)

Comment: What is a "GROPBY timestamp"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may convert your unix timestamp into a string value while querying your table. Just take a look at the [SQLite date funcitons](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

For example you may use the following piece of code in your query:

```
SELECT food_id, COUNT(*) FROM food_logs GROUP BY date(log_date, 'unixepoch');
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction  thing to point out.
When I insert the timestamp in my database I used System.currentTimeMillis() however  SQLite unixepoch take time in seconds so I have to devide by 1000 to save time in seconds and the converted as you suggested

Comment: Just another thing to note: the unix timestamp may be in UTC, if so you will need to correct for that or you may be including entries from (e.g.) the previous evening into the next day's.

Answer (score 1):

The various timestamp values in your table will have distinct values of hour, minute, second.  SQL's GROUP BY is used to collect multiple rows with the **same** value, so that syntax won't work for you here.  If you only need one day's worth of data summed up, you can do something like this, assuming you have a table food_info with columns food_id and calorie_count:

```
SELECT SUM(calorie_count)
    FROM food_logs fl INNER JOIN food_info fi ON fi.food_id = fl.food_id
    WHERE log_date >= '2012-21-05' AND log_date < '2012-21-06'
```

You may have to adjust this a little to fit SQLLite's specific semantics.